# Package/Publish task Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CreateProviderList failed to load Web Deploy assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

> Error  1   Package/Publish task `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CreateProviderList` failed to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended.

The above error is showing when i publish the file from vs 2012. I have already installed web deploy v3.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a late answer but I had this same error message and solved it by installing the Web Deploy extension:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Answer (score 0):

You must install the Web Deploy through Visual Studio Installer

Launch Visual Studio Installer, Go to the Individual components Tab then search "Web Deploy"